# Next.js "Please only return JSON serializable data types." API call from lib

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api, next.js

I am trying to make an API call to later display data on a page. Putting the JS function next to the HTML works fine:

```
export default function Post() {
    const callAPI = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await fetch(
                `http://localhost:8080/all`
            );
            const data = await res.json();
            console.log(data);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };

  return (
    <Layout>
      <button onClick={callAPI}>Make API Call</button>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

However what I really want to do is separate this out into a JS file in /lib. However something is not quite right with parsing and returning the value. Code in the external file is:

```
export async function returnBrian() {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/all');
    let result = await response.json();

    return {
      result,
    };
}
```

Trying to use the value:

```
export default function Post({brian }) {

  return (
    <Layout>
      <p>{brian.brian}</p>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

Error is:

`Error: Error serializing` .brian`returned from`getStaticProps`in "/posts/[id]". Reason:`object `("[object Promise]") cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types.`

I have tried formatting the result value a few different ways but can't get past this error, any tips?

Edit:

My getStaticProps:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  let brian = returnBrian();

  return {
    props: {
      brian,
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: Where is your `getStaticProps` for `/posts/[id]`?

Comment: @vr. I've added this into the post. When I try and pass through a simple string value this is working fine, it's only throwing this error when I'm trying to pass this JSON object.